# Array not giving back letters the user entered

Tags: c, arrays

```
 int read_word(char word[], int max_size_word) {
 {
        int c = 0, let_count = 0;
        printf("\nPlease enter your word: ");
        char input = toupper(getchar());
        for(c = 1; c < 7; c++) {
            if(input != '\n') {
                word[c] = input;   
                let_count++;
            } else if(input == '\n')
              input = toupper(getchar());       //The word the user entered is in word[c]
            }
            return let_count;
         }
    }
    int check_word(char word[], int size_word, int letter_set[], int 
    size_letter_set, int arr[]) 
    {
        char word_copy;
        for(int ii = 0; ii < 7; ii++) {
            word_copy = word[ii];
        }
        printf("The word is %c\n" , word_copy);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm programming a game of scrabble. Here are the two functions that pertain to my question. Basically I want to check if my read word function works. Thats what the bottom printf does. However when I enter a couple letters my "The word is...." printf only gives back the first letter entered. I want the printf to give back every letter entered. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: if you did good formatting of the text you would see that your last printf is outside the loop.

Comment: @serge wouldn't that just make "The word is..." show up 7 times? -I just tested it and thats what it did

Comment: yes, but you are printing single chars, not a word in any case. this way you would see all your chars in the array one by one.

Comment: @serge when I tested it within the loop it gave back 
The word is E

The word is G

The word if G 

and so forth..

Comment: seems like you have several extra sets of braces for no obvious reason.  Also, note that the assignment statement `word_copy = word[ii];` only saves a single character into the variable word_copy.  You will want to do something different to save an entire string.

Comment: yes, as probably expected. you should have an issue with index [0] though, since your first function ignores it. Also, please, fix your formatting of the example. spaces can be freely used to align lines.

Comment: Have you tried the technique of "pretending to be the computer" to understand why your program doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You're only printing one letter because in `printf("The word is %c\n" , word_copy);` your word_copy is a `char` and not a `string`.
In check_word, try replacing

```
char word_copy;
        for(int ii = 0; ii < 7; ii++) {
            word_copy = word[ii];
        }
        printf("The word is %c\n" , word_copy);
    return 0;
```

by

```
int word_size = strlen(word); //calculate the length of your word
char word_copy[word_size + 1]; //create copy string with word size +1 for \0
int ii = 0;
        for(ii; ii < 7; ii++) { //I set ii < 7 to do like you but... Why did you set 7?
            word_copy[ii] = word[ii]; //put the characters of your word into the copy string
        }
    word_copy[ii] = '\0'; //end the string puttin a \0 at its end
    printf("The word is %s\n" , word_copy); //here i replace %c (char) by %s (string)
return 0;
```

There are similar problems in your `read_word` function, you should be able to fix them if you understand the fixes I made in your `check_word` function (even if you can just put your printf in the for loop i think that doing it like so can help you understand the problem in read_word).